# SQL query get distinct records

Tags: sql

I need help with a query to get distinct records from the table.

```
            SELECT distinct cID, firstname, lastname,
             typeId, email from tableA
```

typeId and email has different values in the table. I know this one causing to return 2 records because these values are different.

Is there anyway I can get 1 record for each cID irrespective of typeId and email?

Comment: Do you need the typeId and email at all? (it would suggest not, if you don't care which one you might get) - in which case the simplest thing might be to just drop them from the select - at which point it is distinct on only the things you need, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about what typeId and email get selected with each cID, following is one way to do it.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.cID
        , a.firstname
        , a.lastname
        , b.typeId
        , b.email 
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  cID, MIN(typeID), MIN(email)
          FROM    TableA 
          GROUP BY
                  cID
        ) b ON b.cID = a.cID
```

Answer (score 0):

If any one value for typeId and email are acceptable, then

```
SELECT cID, firstname, lastname, 
  max(typeId), max(email)
 from tableA
 group by  cID, firstname, lastname,
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after:?

> SELECT distinct a.cID, a.firstname,
>   a.lastname, (SELECT typeId from tableA
>   WHERE cID = a.cID), (Select email from
>   tableA WHERE cID = a.cID) from tableA
>   AS a